# What happens when home scanner is discontinued?

Tags: repair

According to this [Fujitsu webpage](https://www.fujitsu.com/global/products/computing/peripheral/scanners/scansnap/discontinued/) and several online reviews, it seems that Fujitsu scanners are "discontinued" after some time.  I am wondering:  does this mean that the scanner will become unusable?  What happens when the software can no longer be updated?  I am wondering if this makes the scanner a bad investment or if this is not an issue.  For what it's worth, I just purchased the S1300i.  Aside from this possible obsolescence issue, the scanner gets glowing reviews.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [diy.se]. But what happened to all those "Pontiac" brand cars when GM folded the brand name? They don't just quit working because the manufacturer is no longer making them. If you like the product, it gets good reviews and it's at a reasonable price, buy it and use it as long as it will continue to connect to your computer. When OS updates make it so the drivers no longer function, buy a replacement.

Comment: People still use Windows XP, not the brightest of ideas.  Scanner should still work, but will not received any updates.  Don't know how much new updates would improve a scanner anyway.

Comment: Thank you @crip659.  That's what I was thinking.

Comment: biggest issue, @crip659, would be driver support. I've got a perfectly good Brother printer collecting dust because I bought it when Win7 was new and it seems that there aren't any Win10 drivers for it. Got lots of good years of use out of it though. Still OT.

Comment: @FreeMan sorry, and the question might be closed for being off-topic.  I just wasn't aware of another stack exchange for my question, and people are much more difficult to talk to on reddit

Comment: superuser.com would have probably worked

Comment: Is that a link?  what is that?

Comment: It’s a SE site: [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thank you @DavidSupportsMonica

Comment: "discontinued" means they no longer sell new ones.  That doesn't reflect their intentions to continue supporting it, they usually call that "obsolete".

Comment: SU mod here - I would close this question as opinion based on [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Discontinued" means the vendor will no longer support the device software wise and parts wise. It doesn't mean the scanner will all of a sudden quit working. You won't be able to get any new improvements to the software and new glitches found it the software won't be fixed but it will continue to operate as it did before the discontinued date. If they change their online platform, you probably won't be able to go there from your devise.

Think of Windows XP... they discontinued it many years ago and quit supporting it but there are still many computers out there still using it. there's just no current support from Microsoft but support groups are out there that can still help.

Comment: In some cases (depending on the technology) the sensor itself may wear out after some time (I have *no idea* if that applies to the particular item here) - an example I am familiar with is carbon monoxide detectors, where the sensor cell has a defined lifetime.

Comment: In the case of older scanners, it is often the light source - probably LEDs now, but in the old days they were high-power bulbs (like projection TV) and they definitely had a limited lifetime and were often not practical to replace.

Comment: if this is a cloud-enabled device  it could stop working (well the cloud features could anyway)